# How to detect unintentional touches when lifting a finger?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitouch

When i drag my finger, my app shows the finger's exact coordinates.

When i lift the finger the coordinates change a bit. They shouldn't.

This only happens when the finger is a thumb and it does happen because when i lift it, the iPad senses one or two more touches (calls touchesMoved) before `touchesEnded` gets called.

I tried to detect this by checking big `pathMajorRadius` changes but it's not effective because these changes can also occur when doing regular dragging movements.

So, i ask, how to reliably detect unintentional touches when lifting a finger off the iPad?

If you need more data, please ask.

Comment: I think it's not possible, what happens when user intentionally moves his finger ?

Comment: Try implementing touchesCancelled

Comment: I have not worked on iPads, but I developed Touch Applications for Microcontrollers using GUI libraries. I was facing a similar problem, and then I dug deeped into the User Manual of the GUIBuilder, that I could get better performance from hardware if I can make changes in paramerters of Touch Sensotivity Driver. Such as In case of resistive screen you can adjust the driver gain for min. and max. pressure values, resistance etc. Check if you any such provisions with your tool.

Comment: @MidhunMP, that's the problem. I want to be able to distinguish that and, from my tests, lifting the thumb fires the `touchesMoved` event when it shouldn't.

Comment: @PrasadTandale, thanks for your suggestion, i will try to research about that.

Answer (score 0):

To check number of touches on screen, you can do the following. In the touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded methods, one parameter is event, which is a UIEvent object. The number of fingers on the screen is [[event allTouches]count]. So if number of touches greater than one, you can edit code so that it wont be taken into consideration.

Comment: Maybe i'm not understanding what you are saying but it's always one finger. Still, i tried your suggestion and the count is always one.